# Nuxt.js - Cannot resolve "@nuxtjs/toast'

Tags: toast, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt to create my frontend application in which I would like to add vue-toasted.
However after installing following the documentation :

> yarn add vue-toasted
>
> add '@nuxtjs/toast' to modules into the nuxt.config.js file

The server cannot build due to this error :

> ERROR  Nuxt error
>
> Error: Cannot resolve "@nuxtjs/toast" from "/front/nuxtjs/toast"

I am running nuxt in a docker container but I already installed depencies succesfully such as bootstrap-vue…

I posted my question on nuxt forum but it seems to be completly dead.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: What is nuxt forum? There is alive nuxt discord channel. And did u install nuxt/toast?

Comment: I am talking about this forum : https://cmty.app/nuxt/modules/issues/c136
I am going to checkout the discord then :)
Yes, I did the yarn add vue-toasted as mentioned in the Readme of nuxt toast page !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was a silly mistake on my hand, it was the package @nuxtjs/toast that needed to be installed and not vue-toasted -.-